# Can't run appimagelauncher second time

Tags: appimage

I downloaded **neovim.appimage** and made it executable

Then I double-clicked it which opened **appimagelauncher** and installed it to ~/Applications

I wanted to move it to a different directory so I used the context menu and selected remove which deleted whatever **appimagelauncher** had done.

I then tried to reinstall it to a different location by double-clicking the original download but **appimagelauncher** did not open.

It looks like **appimagelauncher** thinks it's already installed so double-clicking the appimage won't open **appimagelauncher** anymore. How does appimagelaucher keep track of installed appimages? Is there a file somewhere that needs to be manually deleted so I can run it again on that appimage?

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04